# I need help on how to use the floating point registers

Tags: assembly, mips

So I have written a mips code to find the surface area of a cylinder. I will share pieces of it here....

.text

```
main:

#Get height   
li $v0, 4  #Load syscall print 
la $a0, height  
syscall #print 


#Store height  
li $v0, 6  #read float 
syscall #make the call 
move $t0, $v0   #make height $t0 



#Get radius 
li $v0, 4  #Load syscall print 
la $a0, input2
syscall #print 


#Store radius
li $v0, 6  #read float 
syscall #make the call 
move $t1, $v0   #make radius $t1

li.s $t3, 3.14159265359
li.s $t5, 2.0



#Calculate the surface area 
add.s $t4, $t0, $t1 
mul.s $s0,$t4, $t1 
mul.s $s1, $s0, $t3
mul.s $s2, $t5, $s1
```

I realize that this is not written correctly for floating point numbers as far as the registers are concerned. I need a hand on how I could adjust this to be accurate for floating point numbers. Thank You

Also if you are curious about the math the SA= 2*pi*radius*(radius+height)

EDIT: New attempt with an attempt to convert everything into floating registers

```
.text 

main:

#Get height   
li $v0, 4  #Load syscall print 
la $a0, height  
syscall #print 


#Store height  
li $v0, 6  #read float 
syscall #make the call 
mov.s $f0, $v0   #make height $f0 



#Get radius 
li $v0, 4  #Load syscall print 
la $a0, input2
syscall #print 


#Store radius
li $v0, 6  #read float 
syscall #make the call 
mov.s $f1, $v0   #make radius $f1

li.s $f8, 3.14159265359
li.s $f7, 2.0



#Calculate the surface area 
add.s $f2, $f0, $f1 
mul.s $f3,$f2, $f1 
mul.s $f4, $f3, $f8
mul.s $f6, $f7, $f4
```

The error I get from here is a syntax error in mov.s $f0, $v0

Comment: According to my google-foo, this: https://people.cs.pitt.edu/~childers/CS0447/lectures/SlidesLab92Up.pdf shows how to use floating point registers to do what you need.  Googling "MIPS floating point instructions" got me a bunch of good hits as well.

Comment: Yeah I have seen these kind of things but every time I attempt to implement I have issues. Especially with reading the numbers in from the user and storing them in a useable register

Comment: Are you sure that your read in function accept floats?  If not, you need to convert from int to float or find a read function that works with floats.  Or, you could use fixed point math, but that probably is not where you want to go.

Comment: Let me edit the original post with an attempt to do this with the read in function adjusted

Answer (score 2):

Here goes a sample to get you started:

```
.data
height: .asciiz "Enter height: "
input2: .asciiz "Enter radius: "
pi:  .float 3.14159265359
two: .float 2.0
.text
main:

#Get height   
 li $v0, 4  #Load syscall print 
 la $a0, height  
 syscall #print  

#Store height  
 li $v0, 6  #read float 
 syscall #make the call (input value stored on $f0)
 mov.s $f1, $f0 

#Get radius 
 li $v0, 4  #Load syscall print 
 la $a0, input2
 syscall #print 

#Store radius
 li $v0, 6  #read float 
 syscall #make the call 
 mov.s $f2, $f0

 l.s $f3,  pi
 l.s $f5, two

#Calculate the surface area 

 add.s $f4, $f2, $f1 
 mul.s $f0, $f3, $f5 
 mul.s $f0, $f0, $f2
 mul.s $f12, $f0, $f4

 li $v0, 2  #print float (input expected in $f12)
 syscall #make the call
```

Note that you have to use floating point registers with `add.s`/`mul.s` instructions. Also note that `syscall` 4 returns value on floating point register `f0`

Comment: Ah!  We got an expert to chime in.  Thank you as I'm at best a MIPS hack :)

Comment: Thank you so much...The simplest thing that it was stored in $f0 and $v0 was throwing me off thank you